# Suppress warning log "Could not resolve {assemblyName}"

Tags: c#, logging, .net-6.0

This question refers to .NET 6 code written in C#.

Some of our plugins are in private load contexts. Some things in common, like Newtonsoft assembly, are provided to plugins by the host application and are excluded from the built files according to settings. Everything works as designed.

When the assembly demand occurs, the assembly is not found by the plugin's load context (as expected) and a warning is logged, and then it is successfully obtained from the default load context of the host.

The warning describes as-designed behaviour and pollutes the log, but it's not occurring in our code.

How can this specific warning be suppressed?

We know how to suppress *all* warnings using log levels.

Comment: Can you show some code, eg is it `Assembly.Load()` causing the logging? Releated, they suppressed them at Cake: https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/3337

Comment: Alas it's internal corporate code but thanks for the link, I'll have a good look at that.